# How can I Add an Alt on an Image

Tags: image

I am trying to add a ALT on a picture with alt="{alt_text}" and the engine does not resolve it. Why ?

The width="{width}" works fine

Comment: what field type u use?

Comment: Typo? Check the spelling

Comment: Please expand on your question and add a code example that isn't working. Also, **please** use markdown so your code is readable.